# Use of 'or' before last item in series of items

Tags: attachment-ambiguity

For a particular job, the mandatory educational requirement was:

> A degree with Zoology, Chemistry or Biochemistry as one of the subjects.

Does this sentence mean the requirement is "Zoology + Chemistry" or "Zoology + Biochemistry", or does it mean:
"Zoology or Chemistry or Biochemistry"?

I am from HR team of an organisation and I am looking at interpretation of the above statement. We in India have certain rules for recruitment in Government Organisations and the statement is as per rules book for recruitment for a particular position.

Comment: It's not actually clear what you mean in your last sentence. For example, does "Zoology + Chemistry or Biochemistry" mean "either the combination of zoology and chemistry, or just biochemistry" or does it mean "definitely zoology, plus either chemistry or biochemistry?"

Comment: Context is likely important here. Does the job involve working with animals? Zoology is sufficiently different from Chem and Biochem that I suspect they want a zoologist who has studied one of the other two disciplines. Of course, you can't learn much Biochem well without knowing Chem.

Comment: Katherine, the second statement means definitely Zoology and with Zoology, either Chemistry or Biochemistry.

Comment: The problem is not the three subjects. They are given equal weight in the sentence. The problem is that in the West, we say: **A degree in Zoology, Chemistry or Biochemistry**. We don't say a degree with a, b or c as a subject. This is just like: You can make the recipe with apples, bananas or pears. I don't see any ambiguity at all, punctuation-wise.

Comment: If they are just referring to subjects studied, there is still no ambiguity at all. You have to have studied one of those three subjects.

Answer (score 1):

In spoken or written English,

> Alice, Bob or Charlie

means

> **Alice or Bob or Charlie.**

It also can mean:

> **At least one of (Alice or Bob or Charlie).**

It does not mean:

> *Alice, plus either (Bob or Charlie).*

In your example,

> A degree with Zoology, Chemistry or Biochemistry as one of the subjects.

Is very clear. It means

> **A degree where “Zoology”, or “Chemistry”, or “Biochemistry” was studied.**

Since this is a job posting for “minimum qualifications”, it’s clear that

> **Any combination (such as a “double major” or “triple major”) is also welcomed.**

It *does not mean:*

> A degree where Zoology was studied, plus (your choice of either Chemistry or Biochemistry.)

Comment: That is exactly right.

Answer (score -1):

As it is written, the sentence implies:

> "Zoology or Chemistry or Biochemistry"

As OP already noted, it can be ambiguous, so the educational requirement could be re-written as:

> A degree with Zoology is required
>
> A degree with Chemistry or Biochemistry is **also** required

in order to make sure that more than 1 degree is required.